# Does every differentiable ruled surfaces possess a global ruled parametrization?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

According to my notes, a differentiable ruled surface of $\mathbb R ^3$ is a 2-dimensional $C^k$ submanifold of $\mathbb R ^3$ that can be described as a union of straight lines. I'm working on some problems which seem all to imply that such a surface must possess a parametrization of the form: $$\varphi (s,t)= \gamma (s) + tv(s),$$
where $\gamma\colon I \to \mathbb R^3$ is a regular curve parametrized by arc lenght and $v\colon I \to \mathbb R ^3$ is a vector field along $\gamma$ such that $v$ and $\gamma '$ are linearly independent. In particular, $C=\gamma(I)$ is assumed to be a 1-manifold and the parametrization $\gamma$ is assumed to be periodic if $C$ is diffeomorfic to $S^1$, global if not.

My question is: does every connected ruled surface necessarily admit such a parametrization? How can I explicitly construct one (if possible)?

Comment: It's only a guess, but I think that you can always find the plane that intersects transversally all straight lines of which ruled surface is consisted of. The intersection will be a curve on this plane. However, this intersection might be non-compact, so it would be impossible to parameterize it with arc length. The simplest example -- surface $x^2-y^2 = 1$.

Comment: Hi @Evgeny, thanks for the suggestion. If I make some progress, I will post. Is there anything I can do to improve my question?

Comment: In my opinion the question is quite well posed and no serious improvements are needed. Maybe you just need to refine a little bit a class of surfaces at which you're looking because I've showed you an example of ruled surface which fails to have such parametrization.

Comment: It's funny, but while I was reading Russian translation of this book I suddenly found that Cartan applied his methods to classification of ruled surfaces. I think that you need to take a look at this excerpt: https://books.google.ru/books?id=_8eaAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA156